# DNS Not Found After Installing OpenWRT

Tags: router, dns, internet, openwrt

I have a Netgear WNDR4300 Router. The Internet was working fine before. After I installed OpenWRT to the router, the internet stopped working (I didn't change any setting). All webpage returns an error of "ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED", server DNS address could not be found.

EDIT: I should add that I tried changing DNS address on the openWRT at  `Network > Interface > WAN`, and I checked the DNS address of the network:

```
root@OpenWrt:/# cat /tmp/resolv.conf.auto 
# Interface wan
nameserver 112.124.47.27
nameserver 114.215.126.16
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution to get you back up and running would be to configure your computer to *not* use your router's DNS and use DNS of your own choosing. I suggest 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 which are open DNS servers provided by Google. I use them myself.

You may also configure OpenWRT's DHCP settings (under `Network`>`DHCP and DNS`) to provide these DNS servers to network clients instead of configuring it manually on your computer.

Lastly, you could look at OpenWRT's DNS settings (in the section above) and resolve whatever problem you find there that is preventing DNS from working correctly.

By default OpenWRT does not provide full DNS, just DNS caching. Meaning when you request a web address your computer asks the router, the router checks to see if it already knows the answer and, if not, asks another DNS server from the internet. If you haven't configured OpenWRT with what other DNS server to use that's one thing that could potentially cause this problem. Again, I rather like 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4, but any DNS servers you have been granted permission to use are also perfectly valid (your ISP's DNS servers, for example).

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply! Please see update above (I've tried editing the DNS settings but with no luck). However, I didn't edit under network > DHCP and DNS, as I did not find anything there... I've also tried modifying DNS server settings in my computer, it still gives me the same error.

Comment: Have you verified that you have minimal connectivity? From the command prompt do `ping -n 10 8.8.8.8`. If all time out or are rejected then DNS isn't the problem, but if at least 8 of them succeed then your issue is probably still DNS related. If less than 8 succeed then you may be dealing with serious packet loss issues, which can cause all sorts of weird problems.

Comment: I do not think it's DNS related... I got time out errors when ping or trying to access ip directly.

Comment: You might want to adjust your question to mention that. But I agree, if you got a timeout for all of the ping requests then you are definitely not dealing with a DNS issue.